# How to play flash videos in android application

Tags: android, video, fla

Is there any API for developing an application that can play flash videos on Android OS 2.1.I have searched a lot in Google but cannot find any.

Answer (score 1):

The only player I know on Android 2.1 is [Rockplayer](http://rockplayer.freecoder.org/index_en.html)

Rockplayer itself uses ffmpeg and source codes of how they use ffmpeg in Android are here:
http://rockplayer.freecoder.org/tech_en.html

Comment: Adobe Flash itself maybe? Or also Adobe Air?